# Do the strings for tzitizit need to be made lishma?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, intent-accident-purposely

My weekday tallit is in need of new tzitziot as I am unsure how long they will last before becoming passul. I know that techeilet need to be made from a dye for which a minhag exists, but do the strings need to be made for the purpose of mitzvat tzitzit, or can they be any strings which fulfill the other requirements? (white/off white, wool or linen, et c.)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Your question ("does anyone know where to get tzitziot with techeilet online for relatively little?" and its title ("Do the strings for tzitizit need to be made lishma?") are two completely different questions. Please [edit] the question so they match; as it is, it's difficult to know what question you really mean to ask. Once the question is clear, it can be reopened so people can answer the question you want an answer to. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. I recommend [About] for more on how the site works, or the [help] for more detail on that.

Comment: It looks like you meant to ask one question and then changed gears and asked a different one without changing the title.  If you want, you can ask both questions, but they should be asked separately.  I'd advise changing the title to reflect the question, and then asking a separate question about Lishmah.

Comment: I edited the question although both were relavent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings for Tzitzit (whether they will be white or blue) need to be spun for the express purpose of use in Tzitzit. Some say the material needs to be carded for the express purpose of Tzitzit as well, but most are lenient about this.

([Shulchan Aruch OC 11:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x360))

Comment: See the corresponding Mishnah Berurah for further detail about those who are lenient/stringent.